# Angular app never start

Tags: angular, cmd, windows-10, serve

I'm trying to work with Angular 2, but when I try to start the server with the command `ng serve` nothing happened. The command does nothing, no error message, no status message, anything.

Im running on Windows 10 64-bit, and I think there could be a problem with my computer, I tried in a virtual machine and works fine. I am using a vpn if it's relevant.

I already checked if the port is in use.
I've been trying with cmd in the administrator mode and nothing.

[image]

Can Somebody could help me?
NodeJS version 6.11.5.
Angular/cli version 1.5.0.
NPM version 3.10.10.

UPDATE:

My package.json looks like:

```
{
 "name": "my-app",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "license": "MIT",
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
   "core-js": "^2.4.1",
   "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
   "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
   "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
   "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
   "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
   "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
   "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
   "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
   "karma": "~1.7.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
   "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
   "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
   "protractor": "~5.1.2",
   "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
   "tslint": "~5.7.0",
   "typescript": "~2.4.2"
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your package.json

Comment: When you say nothing does it look like its doing anything at all like a blank line or it just shows the path in the command line like always?

Comment: @rjustin It look like a blank line.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr Yes, of course. I just added.

Answer (score 1):

try to clean and reinstall angular-cli

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

### Possible Solutions:-

```
       1) Uninstall node.js and install latest version of node.js > 8.

      Try to install Visual studio code or other ide's. 

       2)Delete node MOdules and run command- npm install in visual studio code- 'terminal'
       3)Your angular-cli  is latest, so no need to install again.
```

Refer here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli